# Rollup changes import of absolute path to relative path while bundling

Tags: import, rollupjs

I am importing a absolute path in some files of my repo and try to bundle it with rollup
My import where /api/ is absolute path:

```
import * from '/api/myFile.js'
```

But when I bundle it, rollup changes it to relative path and it looks like:

```
import * from  from '../../../../api/myFile.js'
```

And the above path doesn't exist in my app :(

My rollup config:

```
rollup src\\input.js -o lib\\bundle.js -f esm --inlineDynamicImports=true
```

Please help me resolve this issue

I tried making `'/api/'` path as external, that didn't change anything.
And i tried using few rollup plugins - includepaths, root-import,etc nothing worked

Answer (score 1):

Quite late, but for anyone facing this issue: you have to use the [output.paths](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#outputpaths) option. Otherwise rollup tries to resolve it with a weird root path (in my case even not a CWD, HDD root?).

In this case (skipping non-relevant flags):

```js
output: {
    paths: {
      api: '/api'
    }
}
```

And then just import it:

```js
import * from 'api/myFile.js'
import * from 'api/otherFile.js'
```

Note no leading `/` - it is now a kind of absolutely mapped module.